# How can I make this dropdown in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, dropdown

[Here is the default structure for dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylXr0.png)

[This is when you click the dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8HKL.png)

I'm new to react native and I was wondering how can I make this kind of structure.
If anyone can help, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll have a little more success if you call this component an "accordion" in your searching. "Dropdown" sort of suggests a [picker component](https://reactnative.directory/?search=picker) to me.

I searched for "React Native accordion" and found [this medium post that seems relevant](https://kps250.medium.com/creating-an-accordion-in-react-native-f313748b7b46). I might start there.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the correct term was in fact Accordion. I appreciate your help brother!